# MS-Access Logic, using query to change people on charge

Tags: ms-access, logic

I have a table with info like: 
Item - Person in charge

Then, I have another with Batch - Item

One batch can have many items, but each have one person. Meaning a batch could end up having many people on charge... that won't do, I need only one, the one with the most items in the batch.

First I made a query with Batch, Item, Person (as there are other variables, there were a lot of repeated lines)
Then I use the count function, to have only "unique" lines.
Next I query by batch, person and a sum of the counts.
Then a batch and max of the counts.
Then I managed to link the sum to the max (didn't use sql, but when I try to open, it only does in that mode)

The problem is: there is stuff missing...

I did it in Excel using a cross table and a index match max formula... 
I need it to show all, and when/if cannot assign to someone, then it would assign to a designated person (I did an iferror in Excel)

There is an example of what I want to do:

**batch** - b
**item** - i
**person** - p

```
i1=p1    
i2=p1    
i3=p2    
i4=p3    

b1 i1 p1    
b1 i1 p1    
b1 i3 p2    

b2 i1 p1    
b2 i2 p1    
b2 i4 p3    
b2 i4 p3    
b2 i4 p3    
b2 i3 p2    

b1 i1 p1    
b1 i2 p1    
b1 ix xxx
```

It should be like:

```
b1 i1 p1
b1 i1 p1    
b1 i3 p1    

b2 i1 p3    
b2 i2 p3    
b2 i4 p3    
b2 i4 p3    
b2 i4 p3    
b2 i3 p3    

b1 i1 xxx    
b1 i2 xxx    
b1 ix xxx
```

If there's a "tie" it could go to anyone with no problem at all. And if there's one it can't find, then it assigns to someone specific.

There could be a exception where if there is at least one peculiar item, the whole batch would need to go to someone specific...

I am still newbie at Access and still thinking as Excel... cannot really see a solution to that using what I know (queries, criteria and some functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT Batch, Item, 
(SELECT TOP 1 Person FROM Items I2 
WHERE I2.Batch = Items.Batch 
GROUP BY I2.Batch, I2.Person 
ORDER BY Count(I2.Person) DESC) As PersonInCharge
FROM Items
```

If you want to get the Person details in the same query it's a little more complex:

```
SELECT Batch, Item, Persons.PersonName
FROM (Items INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT I3.BatchID, I3.Person
    FROM Items AS I3 GROUP BY I3.Batch, I3.Person) AS BatchPerson
    ON Items.Batch = BatchPerson.Batch) 
   INNER JOIN Persons ON BatchPerson.Person = Persons.Person
WHERE (((BatchPersons.Person)=
   (SELECT TOP 1 I2.Person 
    FROM Items I2 
    WHERE I2.Batch = Items.Batch 
    GROUP BY I2.Batch, I2.Person 
    ORDER BY COUNT(I2.Person) DESC)))
```

I'm assuming some of the table and field names above.